# create react app error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I just created a folder called client and ran the command

```
npx create-react-app ./
```

After that, when I run

```
npm start
```

I am getting the following error.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at processModule (C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:93:38)
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:5:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:781:30
    at MultiModule.build (C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiModule.js:39:10)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
    at C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1111:12
    at MultiModuleFactory.create (C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiModuleFactory.js:18:3)
    at C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1063:18
    at Semaphore.acquire (C:\Users\Vishruth S\NodeJS_progs\mernstack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\Semaphore.js:29:4)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vishruth S\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-19T14_02_31_823Z-debug.log
```

I haven't modified any files from the default create-react-app, yet I am not able to run it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write

```
npx create-react-app client
```

the above line will create a react project under the folder 'client'
you don't have to manually create any thing

look into the documentation if you need

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the command be :

`npx create-react-app .`

Comment: Oh I am actually new to this, and I was following the commands from a youtube tutorial